# javascript onclick inside td tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to submit a `<form>` with `<table>` inside it. How to submit that `<form>` with default action? With `<select>` tag I can submit a form with `onchange` javascript function. I thought that `onclick="this.form.submit"` inside `<td>` tag would solve, but firebug indicates error: `TypeError: this.form is undefined`

What is wrong?

```
<div class="report">
  <form method="post" name="status_students">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td class="tdreport">Active</td>
        <td class="tdreport">Unstable</td>
        <td class="tdreport">Inactive</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="active" name="students_actives" value="actives" onclick="this.form.submit()">
          <?php
          if ($this->siteCenterSelected == "All") {
          echo count($this->usersStatus['verde']);
          } else {
          echo count($this->usersStatusSiteCenter['verde']);
          }
          ?>
        </td>
        <td class="unstable"><?php
          if ($this->siteCenterSelected == "All") {
          echo count($this->usersStatus['amarelo']);
          } else {
          echo count($this->usersStatusSiteCenter['amarelo']);
          }
          ?>
        </td>
        <td class="inactive"><?php
          if ($this->siteCenterSelected == "All") {
          echo count($this->usersStatus['vermelho']);
          } else {
          echo count($this->usersStatusSiteCenter['vermelho']);
          }
          ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `this` in your scenario refer to the td element, a quick a dirty solution would be to going up in the dom using `.parent` -> `this.parent.parent.parent`. You could also find your form by his name. `document.status_students`

Comment: Try `document.status_students.submit()`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` object you're referring to in the *onclick* function is the clicked `td`, not the entire document. You may want to use this instead:

```
onclick="document.forms[0].submit()"
```

But indeed, you should better refer to the form by its ID instead.

Comment: As note, if you have more than one form, change the index, since `[0]` represents the first form element.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tao. In fact, I've create a function called by `onclick` inside `td` tag, that submit form with `document.getElementById("status_students").submit()`.